# Blogger: Facebook share - issue with image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, blogger

When I try to share any content of my blogger in facebook or if I just copy the link and paste there something like this happen (see the empty square that is supposed to have an image):

[image: daniel cajueiro blogger]

I have tried to take a look at [Facebook developer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and it says that:

```
Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Share App ID Missing    The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
```

I have tried to follow some solutions that I found:

1) Edit HTML and just above the `</head>` tag paste the following piece of code.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='http://www.your-blog-logo.jpg' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
```

2) search for `<b:includable id='post' var='post'>` and paste the below code after this tag

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
<b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:post.firstImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
<meta content='1200' property='og:image:width'/>
<meta content='630' property='og:image:height'/>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
<meta content='1200' property='og:image:width'/>
<meta content='630' property='og:image:height'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-9Fy3-ME-5VA/VfhZDh1oQOI/AAAAAAAABFc/SPkLmVpV1aY/s1600/no-thumbanil-available.png' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='og:description'/>
<b:else/>
<meta expr:content='data:post.snippet' name='og:description'/>
</b:if>
```

None of these solutions solved the problem. Can you help me?

Comment: Try adding the meta tags in the `<head>` tag in the template. Also,do "Fetch new scrape information" in [Facebook Developer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) as Facebook is known to cache old sharing information.  Always use the blogspot.com of the blog post when doing the  "Fetch new scrape information" , the reason for this being that whenever you share your blog on Facebook , irrespective of the ccTLD (aka blogspot.dk ,blogspot.co.uk ,etc) of the URL , always the blogspot.com version is shared. I did this for the latest post & now it shows the image when sharing.

Comment: It seems that you are right and I was having some problems with "old information". I will make some more tests!